# Read part of column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL Server 2012 table:

```
create table dbo.Packs {
  Id int identity not null,
  Info nvarchar (200) not null
}
```

How can I get all rows where Info starts with "File" ... I might have:

```
"File #200 View", "File #100 Delete", "Stat F#20"
```

So I would get the first two records.

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`LIKE` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) with the % wildcard:

```
SELECT [Id], [Info]
FROM [dbo].[Packs]
WHERE [Info] LIKE 'File%'
```

Example

```
CREATE TABLE packs ([Info] varchar(16));

INSERT INTO packs ([Info])
VALUES ('File #200 View'), ('File #100 Delete'), ('Stat F#20');

SELECT [Info] FROM [packs] WHERE [Info] LIKE 'File%';
```

Returns

```
|             INFO |
|------------------|
|   File #200 View |
| File #100 Delete |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/689d5/1)

Comment: There is a SQL Fiddle to? Great ... Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id,
       Info 
FROM Packs 
WHERE Info LIKE 'File%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LIKE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) with a wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Packs WHERE Info LIKE 'File%'
```

The link above has a reference of the available wildcards; you want to match any string, including zero characters, after the `File` part so you want the `%` wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Packs] WHERE [Info] LIKE 'File%'
```

Should do the trick :)